# SpreadJs is not showing some fonts correctly

Tags: javascript, spreadjs

When using SpreadJs, if I set the font to Roboto, then the spreadsheet displays the font incorrectly.

Is there a way to add custom fonts or am I setting this incorrectly?

I am setting using the following format, this works for a select set of fonts but not others.

```
let fontText = `${fontWeight} ${fontSizes}px ${fontFamilies}`;
style.font = fontText;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found it was because I didn't have Roboto installed, I added the following link at the top of my page and this solved the issue.

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">`